# Rails console in production: NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, production

I have a rails app (rails 5). In development, everything work, when i use

```
rails console
```

And enter an instruction, for example `User.all` , it's working.

In production, my app work perfectly, no problems, no errors, but when i use `rails console production` and enter for example `User.all` i have an error :

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):2
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/alexandre/tcheen/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `load'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:191:in `block in serve'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/alexandre/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have the same problem with all my classes, but i repeat, the application work perfectly.
I develop on Mac OS and the app run in production on debian 8.
My models are correctly named i verified.
Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you type `::User.all`?

Comment: Thanks but it work after a new ssh session

Comment: Having this same issue suddenly. No idea what happened

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I had this problem and realized it happened after I made a tweak to one of my job files.
What fixed it was restarting the spring loader.  Just run

```
spring stop
```

Then the next time you run the `rails console` it should load things as normal.

Comment: You are such a life-saver! I was stuck on this issue since more than 3 weeks. You really saved it for me :)

Comment: @JagjotSingh sorry you didn't see it sooner! It also confused me for a long time!  Glad it helped you now though!

Comment: Lost a couple of gray hairs over this one.  Thanks.

Comment: this was bugging me for a while, but mine was really random, like, come back in 1min and it'll be fixed random, but today I really needed it asap, appreciate it.. a couple of solutions in the long term: 1- disable it on production https://github.com/rails/spring#temporarily-disabling-spring or use the groups of bundle http://bundler.io/v1.12/groups.html.
I was so, so sure that it would overwrite the Gemfile.lock, but apparently I'm just an ass(I told that too many times xd)

Comment: YOU ARE A LIFE-SAVER MAN!! YOU ARE!

Comment: fwiw `spring stop` did not work for me, yet I did have a spring process via `ps -ef | grep spring`.  After killing that process, the console loaded as mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, [rewolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40457309/10907864) above solved it for me **temporarily**.

**Just to add to his answer:**

After stopping the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem by running the command below

```
spring stop
```

You can also fix this issue **permanently** by upspringing (removing the spring gem from) your `bin/` executables:

```
bin/spring binstub --remove --all
```

Or

```
spring binstub --remove --all
```

You can now run the command below to get into rails console in production

```
rails c --environment=production
```

Also, to avoid this from occurring in subsequent occasions endeavour to make sure that the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem is only present in `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile.

Moreso, when you're in production make sure you always provide the `--without development test` argument to the `bundle install` command

```
bundle install --without development test
```

and not the usual or common

```
bundle install
```

**Please note:** As an indication, whenever you run the command `rails c` or `rails console` and you see the output below:

> Running via Spring preloader in process 26651
>   WARNING: Spring is running in production. To fix this make sure the spring gem is only present in `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile and make sure you always use `bundle install --without development test` in production

It's an indication that the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem is running in your production environment, and it should be stopped or removed entirely from your bin executables.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**