# Cannot load my model in console rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to view what is on my Tasks table and all of the sudden I am now getting a `uninitialized constant` error. I cannot think why this is happening. The page is working fine. By the way, I do have a task.rb in my model.

```
server@server:~/www/railsapp/$ rails c production
Running via Spring preloader in process 27137
Loading production environment (Rails 5.1.1)
irb(main):001:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
   (0.3ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
=> ["ar_internal_metadata", "schema_migrations", "tasks", "users"]
irb(main):002:0> Task.all
NameError: uninitialized constant Task
    from (irb):2
irb(main):003:0>
```

**I posted the solution for my problem below**

Comment: is the file Task.rb exists in app/model folder?

Comment: Do you have change you `Task` model?

Comment: Yes I have a task model.

Comment: @Alejandro Montilla No. However, for some reason it started working again. I change some JavaScript stuff and I did a `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and then I restarted passenger and the problem came back.

Comment: @myhouse try this one `Rails.application.eager_load!`

Comment: I found the solution by doing 'spring stop'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found out the solution for the problem. It was Spring causing the issue. I provided the link to the StackOverflow question down below.

I had to run in the terminal:

```
spring stop
```

Now when I start my console it can read my models.

[The link I found for solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438109/rails-console-in-production-nameerror-uninitialized-constant)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `task.rb` in `app/models` folder:

## app/model/task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  
end
```

Comment: I have this. I am using rails 5.1

Answer (score 0):

That mean for some reason rails did not load file where your model(class name) live.

If your "page" work I suppose that you change something  in application but not restart your production(production work on old code). @Alejandro Montilla  ask about changes but you didn answer

Comment: I just reply to Alejandro. Yes, my model is behaving weird. I restarted the application and for some reason the console cannot read the model but the page can.