# Rails crashes console saying it can't find Devise Invitable, but server has no issues loading it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, console, devise-invitable

When trying to run the rails console:

```
bundle exec rails console
```

The console crashes with the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Devise::Models::Invitable (NameError)
```

but launching the server:

```
bundle exec rails server
```

starts the server without issue, and the app works as expected. The test suite is also all green.

What is different in the console that would cause it to crash? What can I do to resolve this issue?

Full stack trace:

```
/Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Devise::Models::Invitable (NameError)
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/models.rb:90:in `const_get'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/models.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in devise'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/models.rb:89:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/models.rb:89:in `block in devise'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/models.rb:116:in `devise_modules_hook!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/models.rb:86:in `devise'
  from /Users/username/workspace/project/app/models/user.rb:16:in `<class:User>'
  from /Users/username/workspace/project/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise.rb:350:in `new'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise.rb:350:in `add_mapping'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
  from /Users/username/workspace/project/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
  from /Users/username/workspace/project/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `catch'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `block in default_terminator'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:110:in `run!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:115:in `run!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in reload!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:51:in `tap'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:51:in `block in reload!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:50:in `reload!'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:168:in `serve'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/username/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try to remove`/tmp/cache` locally before running console?

Comment: `/tmp/cache` does not exist, but `tmp/cache` does in the project directory. I just tried clearing it per your suggestion and it didn't not make a difference.

Comment: are you running spring by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438109/rails-console-in-production-nameerror-uninitialized-constant

Comment: thanks @beniutek, that was the issue. I'd completely forgotten about spring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails console in production: NameError: uninitialized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438109/rails-console-in-production-nameerror-uninitialized-constant)

Answer (score 0):

> spring stop

command then

> rails c

worked for me on mac catalina